# Writing a list to a text file using Python

Tags: python-2.7, text, save

I have a list in this format,

**some_list=['com', 'kill', 'someone', 'get', 'caught']**

And i need this to be written on to a text file as,

**com kill someone get caught**

Basically i need spaces between words.
However, i have tried methods such as,

```
for f in some_list:
  f.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in f) + '\n')
```

```
" ".join(map(str, f))
```

Non of the above seem to work to get my outcome. Any help?

Comment: Please read: [ask]

Comment: Is there any problem on how i have asked the question? Apparently three people have understood the question. @3D1T0R

Comment: You don't show how you initialize the variables you're using. You state that `f` is the previously mentioned list, but based on the code shown that does not appear to be the case, rather, at a guess, it looks to be the file you're trying to write to, but how are we supposed to know that seeing as you could have named the list `f`. Anyone who answered was guessing at what you must have done in other parts of your code because they could not have possibly known based on what you actually said.

Comment: But i have mentioned **Where f is the list of words** doesn't that imply **f= ['com', 'kill', 'someone', 'get', 'caught']** ?

Comment: You state that `f` is the list of words, but then in your code you write `some_list` where the list of words would be, and try to run `f.write()` after using `f` to iterate through `some_list`, causing it to become a string. Lists and strings don't have a `.write()` method. That's for files. If you had simply included the part(s) of your code where you had defined `f` and `some_list` then the people answering wouldn't have been working off of assumptions, they would have had real information to go off of.

Comment: Yes, there can be a small confusion the way you put it in. BTW thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,
**f** is your text file

```
your_list = ['com', 'kill', 'someone', 'get', 'caught']
f.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in your_list))
```

Output: 
**com kill someone get caught**

Comment: `your_list` or `some_list`? :)

Comment: Any list like OP has asked

Comment: yes, but check your code - you initialize `your_list` but use `some_list` in the second line

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open('myfile', 'w')
some_list = ['com', 'kill', 'someone', 'get', 'caught']

f.write(" ".join(some_list))
```

Comment: actually, as OP asked how to write to file, EDITed my response to include writing to file

Answer (score 0):

you have a list containing a number of values in your cause you have ['com', 'kill', 'someone', 'get', 'caught']

```
temp=""
for f in some_list:
     temp= temp+f+' '
#now save your text into a file
#now we have temp="com kill someone get caught"
```